# Use a custom texture in material nodes in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

So, I created this procedural grid texture using nodes in Blender, which I plan on using as a Bump map for normals.

[image]
[image]
But I have no clue how to use this texture I made in the material node editor. It does not show up as an option on the image texture node. How do I use a texture I made in the material node editor?

Comment: You apparently created a node texture for Blender internal, you can't use Blender internal node setups in Cycles, nor vice-versa. Either recreate it using Cycles nodes, which seems quite possible, or render it to an image, save it as a file and use that as an image texture in Cycles.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I made the node setup in cycles... why is it in BI? Does cycles not support prodecural textures?

Comment: Actually my mistake, those are not Blender Internal Nodes, those appear to be Texture Pain Nodes or something like that, never seen those before. Either way, problem is the same, bottom line is if you want to use the texture in Cycles then use Cycles Nodes, nothing else.